# Can I use "great" for a work or something?

Tags: word-usage

Which sentence should I use?

> Your work is great.
>   Your work is very good.

> Your cloth is great.
>   Your cloth is very good.

Comment: Structurally and grammatically, there's not much difference. I would say that "great" is generally considered to be better than "very good", but that's not a fixed scale, and both words express favorable opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Great* can be informally used to mean "very good or pleasant," as in the following sentences:

> It's great to see you again.

> What a great goal!

> You have been a great help, I must say.

*Great* can also be used to mean "important and impressive."

> The wedding was a great occasion.

> The great thing is to get it done quickly.
>
> One great advantage of this metal is that it doesn't rust.

In your examples, *great* could simply mean "very good" or *impressive*. You can use *great* instead of "very good."

Answer (score 1):

*Great* can be used in at least two ways. It can describe something that is truly outstanding when it is applied, for example, to a work of art or literature. Equally, you can say it when you want to say something flattering about someone’s clothes, taste in interior decoration, or cookery skills.

Comment: Curiously, although the second usage seems a synonym of *terrific*,
 I have yet to find a suitable synonym for the first usage.

Comment: @tchrist masterful?